# Is there an altenative way of saying »habe sein dürfen«?

Tags: modal-verb, tense

I came across the following sentence in [Der Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/usa-hillary-clinton-bietet-donald-trump-zusammenarbeit-an-a-1120569.html):

> Speziell wandte sich [Hillary] Clinton auch an ihre Unterstützerinnen:
>   Ihnen sagte Clinton, sie sollten wissen, dass sie nichts stolzer mache, als dass sie ihre Vorkämpferin **habe sein dürfen**.

As I understand it, the last portion of the above sentence can be translated as follows:

> ... that nothing makes her more proud than the fact that she could have been (*or* had the honor of having been) their standard bearer.

Can *habe sein dürfen* be replaced by a simpler tense in the above sentence?

Also, what’s the name of the tense, in which *habe sein dürfen* is used above?

Comment: Someone has the original english speech where Spiegel derived from?

Comment: @ Thomas Here is the portion of the speech: "And so we need — we need you to keep up these fights now and for the rest of your lives. And to all the women, and especially the young women, who put their faith in this campaign and in me: I want you to know that nothing has made me prouder than to be your champion." Link: http://www.vox.com/2016/11/9/13570328/hillary-clinton-concession-speech-full-transcript-2016-presidential-election

Comment: The correct unpoetic translation would be: "Ich möchte euch wissen lassen, daß mich nichts stolzer gemacht hat, als eure Anführerin gewesen zu sein."

Comment: @Thomas I also linked it in my answer. (Eugene, there must not be a space between @ and the username of the person you want to ping or it will not register ;) However, the auto-pinging settings probably pinged Thomas, anyway.)

Comment: @Thomas Wie kommen alle von *champion* auf *Anführerin/Vorkämpferin?*

Comment: The strange translation is a original from Reuters by the way.

Comment: @Jan, IMHO in english Champion has a broader meaning than in German, so you have to translate more specific from the context, however all these emotional speeches in these times seem to allow everything. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tense of the construction *habe sein dürfen* is the perfect tense in conjunctive I mood; it uses an *Ersatzinfinitiv* rather than the more systematic *sein gedurft habe* — which, as a side note, sounds horrible to my ears. In indicative mood, it would probably be transformed into a preterite form in a newspaper:

> Nichts macht mich stolzer, als dass ich eure Vorkämpferin **sein durfte.**

---

The speech in video form and a transcript can be found on [hillaryspeeches.com](https://hillaryspeeches.com/2016/11/09/hillary-clinton-calls-for-unity-in-concession-speech/). I suspect the passage in question is the following:

> And to all the women, and especially the young women, who put their faith in this campaign and in me: I want you to know that nothing has made me prouder than to be your champion.

Translated, the part behind the colon could read:

> Ich möchte, dass ihr wisst, dass nichts mich stolzer machte, als euer Champion zu sein.

Since this is a newspaper article, it will use reported speech which requires finite verbs to change to conjunctive I wherever possible. That renders as:

> Sie sagte, dass nichts sie stolzer gemacht habe, als ihr Champion **zu sein.**

Note that it doesn’t require a *dürfen* nor a *habe.* The full verb *machen,* however, changed from indicative to conjunctive.

Possibly, the newspaper decided to restructure the sentence altogether and add an additional full verb (here *dürfen)* to overcome any issues with pronouns. If they had left it in the way I suggested, potential ambiguity arises *whose* champion Hillary considers herself to be (her own?).

Comment: @CarstenS How true, I totally overlooked that!

Comment: Some small addition to Jans answer:
The use of this special construct in the translation is a typical poetic style which sounds even more gentle than simpler forms, expressing the honour and pride of have been in this role of the champion.

From my point of view the horrible translation from the original text is meant to further underline Clintons distance from normal people. In fact the original text is rather simple: "I want you to know that nothing has made me prouder than to be your champion."

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, the original text is quoted and linked in the answer ;)

Comment: I am asking me if it is really a "conjunctive" and if it is which one really? Do you have references explaining this?

Comment: @Thomas Which one? The original speech uses an infinitive construction; very common in English. My translation below the line does, too; an infinitive does not change mood. The newspaper transformed the infinitive into a subordinate clause which was turned into a conjunctive. Reported speech is always conjunctive I; conjunctive II is reserved for potentialities (‘ich wäre gerne …’).

Comment: @Thomas, „habe“ ist Konjunktiv I.

Answer (score -1):

*sie habe sein dürfen* is Konjunktiv II of *sie durfte sein*.

**Sein durfte** is the same in indicative mood. I think indicative is also more appropriate here, as Clinton indeed *was* a *Vorkämpferin* — the fact she lost doesn't change that.

Remember what Mark Twain said about German newspapers. That was 130 years ago. Nothing has changed.

Comment: »Mache dich niemals mit einer Sache gemein; auch nicht mit einer guten«, ist ein alter Journalistengrundsatz. Dieser wäre im Indikativ verletzt.

Comment: Es ist die Wiedergabe einer Aussage Clintons. So wie sie da steht kann man sie in den Indikativ setzen, denn sie hat diese Aussage auch im Indikativ getätigt.

Comment: Indikativ verlangt Anführungszeichen; es wurde entschieden auf Anführungszeichen zu verzichten, ergo Konjunktiv.